# While statement with multiple conditions

Tags: c#, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have the following **while** statement -

```
while ((!testString.Contains("hello")) && (NewCount != OldCount) && (attemptCount < 100))
{
    //do stuff (steps out too early)
}
```

This is stepping out of the statement even though all the conditions have not been met.

I have tried to reduce it like -

```
while (!testString.Contains("hello"))
{
    // this works and steps out when it should
}
```

And this steps out when `hello` is present for example. I also tried changing this to an **OR** statement which reversed the problem to never stepping out the statement.

Addint the `&& (NewCount != OldCount) && (attemptCount < 100))` conditions is causing this behaviour how can I resolve this?

Comment: What are the values of `NewCount`, `OldCount` and `attemptCount`?

Comment: I'm thinking you need to provide more context for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is stepping out of the statement even though all the conditions
>   have not been met.

To achieve that you need to specify logical `OR` (`||`). 
For example:

```
while ((!testString.Contains("hello")) || (NewCount != OldCount) || (attemptCount < 100))
{
    //while at least one those conditions is true, loop will work
}
```

Which means that inside loop you need to introduce security checks, *where required*, for conditions which are not more true, while loop is still executing.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to Tigran´s answer. Often (in order to avoid mess with the complex condition) it could be useful to push the condition into the loop:

```
  while (true) { // loop forever unless:
    if (testString.Contains("hello")) // ...test string contains "hello"
      break;

    if (NewCount == OldCount) // ...counts are equal
      break;

    if (attemptCount >= 100) // ... too many attempts
      break;

    // ...it's easy to add conditions (as well as comment them out)  when you have them

    // Loop body
  }
```